# Exception startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord

Tags: java, android, audio-recording

I have an application that uses an audio recorder. But he constantly gives an error when I click on the "start record" button. I indicated the permission in the manifest and registered them in the activity lane. For the test, I use galaxy s10 api 29. Any ideas?

```
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7777)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1047)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:6425)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7870) 
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14966) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7839) 
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:886) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29315) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7777) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1047) 
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.
    at android.media.AudioRecord.startRecording(AudioRecord.java:1097)
    at ru.mirea.belov.del1.MainActivity.recordStart(MainActivity.java:66)
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
final String TAG = "myLogs";
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_AUDIO = 100;
private String PERMISSIONS = Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO;

private boolean isWork;

int myBufferSize = 8192;
AudioRecord audioRecord;
boolean isReading = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    isWork = hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS);
    if (!isWork) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_AUDIO) ;
    }

    createAudioRecorder();

    Log.d(TAG, "init state = " + audioRecord.getState());
}

void createAudioRecorder() {
    int sampleRate = 8000;
    int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
    int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

    int minInternalBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate,
            channelConfig, audioFormat);
    int internalBufferSize = minInternalBufferSize * 4;
    Log.d(TAG, "minInternalBufferSize = " + minInternalBufferSize
            + ", internalBufferSize = " + internalBufferSize
            + ", myBufferSize = " + myBufferSize);

    audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat, internalBufferSize);
}



public void recordStart(View v) {
    Log.d(TAG, "record start");
    audioRecord.startRecording();
    int recordingState = audioRecord.getRecordingState();
    Log.d(TAG, "recordingState = " + recordingState);
}

public void recordStop(View v) {
    Log.d(TAG, "record stop");
    audioRecord.stop();
}

public void readStart(View v) {
    Log.d(TAG, "read start");
    isReading = true;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (audioRecord == null)
                return;

            byte[] myBuffer = new byte[myBufferSize];
            int readCount = 0;
            int totalCount = 0;
            while (isReading) {
                readCount = audioRecord.read(myBuffer, 0, myBufferSize);
                totalCount += readCount;
                Log.d(TAG, "readCount = " + readCount + ", totalCount = "
                        + totalCount);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public void readStop(View v) {
    Log.d(TAG, "read stop");
    isReading = false;
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    isReading = false;
    if (audioRecord != null) {
        audioRecord.release();
    }
}

public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull
        int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_AUDIO) {
        isWork = grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
}
```

}

There is permission in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>
```

What's wrong ? Help me pls.